# Storing Image path as single forward slash in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, ravendb

I am uploading image to a folder and saving its path in db.Here is my code.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadPic(FileManagement fmanage, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    string email = User.Identity.Name;
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var FileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", Guid.NewGuid(), Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads"), FileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);
        using (var session = DocumentStore.OpenSession("RavenMemberShip"))
        {
            var query = from q in Session.Query<Registration>() where q.Email == email select q;
            if (query.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var updated in query)
                {
                    updated.FileName = FileName;
                    updated.Path = path;
                    session.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Remove the errors and try again");

    return View();
}
```

But the path is stored as double forward slash,which is wrong.How can i save  the path as single slash.
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said the path is stored with a "double forward slash", which would be `//`.  I think you meant a "double *backslash*", which would be `\\`.  Please provide an example if I am mistaken.

The double backslash is appropriate, because it escapes the backslash character.  A value such as `\n` would be a newline, so an actual backslash has to be escaped as `\\`.  This is part of how JSON stores strings.

However, you might want to consider only storing the file name into your document.  The full path to the uploads folder is just going to be redundant.  If you ever want to change it, then you should just be able to edit a setting instead of having to modify all of your documents.

Other issues with your code:

- Remove this line:

  ```
  if (query.Count() > 0)
  ```

  It is unnecessary, and is causing the query to be executed twice.
- This line:

  ```
  session.SaveChanges();
  ```

  Needs to be moved *after* your `foreach` loop.  You only want a single batch of changes sent to RavenDB.
- Use consistent naming conventions.  The `FileName` local variable should be cased as `fileName`.

Comment: Got your point.Modified my source code,now it is working as expected.Thanks!